# how do I determine the source of a sequence in my final contigs

Tags: sequence, fastq

if I have a sequence of 1118 contig sequence in a file (final.contig.fa), how do I determine the biological sequence of all the 1118  sequence in this file?

i ran cat final.contig.fa and it gave me the first 40 sequence , so i ran BLAST on those. but i have a total contig of 1118 sequence.